# Debugging in IE8/9 & CSS

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer-9

For some reason a website that recently went live has now completely screwed in IE9. Not sure what has happened to screw it all up but I'm left desperately needing to apply the fixes as the site is actually live.

There are some major ones and some minor ones.

The site is http://bit.ly/8oRMih

The site views fine in Firefox and Chrome.

When viewed in IE9, the left hand sidebar (left_column) doesn't appear horizontally level with the jQuery slider (jtabslider).

The CSS for the id left_column is...

```
clear: left;
width: 200px;
margin-top: -34px;
margin-right: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
border-left: 4px solid #990000;
border-right: 4px solid #990000;
border-bottom: 4px solid #990000;
```

None of our designers are free currently and I'm simply hopeless at debugging for IE so would be really grateful if any CSS wizards could lend a hand in resolving the issues if possible please.

Let me know if there is more info needed from me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Validate your HTML.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buypubquiz.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

The problem is the first issue listed:

> No DOCTYPE found! Checking with default XHTML 1.0 Transitional Document Type.

No doctype means that IE is using [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) which emulates IE5.5. Which sucks. So your site looks broken.

Comment: Oh for goodness sake! Thank you so much for pointing this out, I think I know how this has happened. Prestashop has a tool in the back office for compressing all source etc and it looks like the moron that built it has stripped out everything from the page that isn't wrapped in tags meaning that the doctype has been stripped (which is clearly included at the top of the header file). Unbelievable. :/ Thanks very much thirtydot.

Comment: Just to add to the above, I edited the compression script, reinstating doctype and this fixed all the problems... Thanks ever so much.